# Bitrise: How to add second "Git Clone Repository" step to a workflow?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bitrise

I'm using [Bitrise](https://bitrise.io) for CI/CD.

The `Git Clone Repository` build step uses the environment variable `GIT_REPOSITORY_URL` as an input to determine where to clone from.

I'd like to add a second step to clone another repository, but it seems like it is not possible to specify a different url to clone from.

If there is, can somebody tell me how to do that, or, alternatively, does anyone have an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works for me:
In our company project, Bitrise CI first runs the `Activate SSH key`step, then the `Git Clone Repository` (which of course needs the first one for authentication)  step from their library.

Now when this is done, I still can't use another `Git Clone Repository` because of the limitation described in the question, but it's very easy to access another repository that uses the same credentials in a script. So that's what I did. My second repo is accessible with the same SSH key, so all I needed was a `script`build step that does this:

```
git clone git@github.com:myrepo [my\desired\location]
```

to get my second repo.